# Eventos onmouseover y onmouseout en botón con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eventos

El HTML que muestro contiene código JavaScrpipt con el que pretendo cambiar el color de un elemento tan solo cuando el puntero está sobre él. Sin embargo no consigo que al sacar  el puntero del botón, éste retome el color original.

He usado `.backgroundColor='none'` además de `'default'`, pero no lo consigo. Sé que puedo hacerlo usando un color picker sobre el color original y luego añadírselo con un `onmouseout`; pero eso me traería el problema que a un usuario con algún tema cargado no le retornase al color original.

¿Cuál sería la solución ideal en este caso?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript HTML Events</h2>
<button onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red'"
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='default'"
    onclick="this.innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El color `default` no existe. El [valor por defecto del background-color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) es `transparent`.

Por lo tanto debes usar:

```
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent'"
```

o bien

```
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''"
```

y entonces cogerá el por defecto, que es `transparent`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript HTML Events</h2>
<button onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red'"
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''"
    onclick="this.innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>
</body>
</html>
```